# Java Fx jar runtime Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar

Im trying to create my first executable jar with javaFx and maven. But after compiling I cannot run this cuz after running command:

```
java -jar mfe_ttn70_arn_detector_final.jar
```

Im getting error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

In some existing solutions ppl advised to use also parameters like:

```
java -jar mfe_ttn70_arn_detector_final.jar --module-path –D:\programming\javafx-sdk-19\lib --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.fxml,javafx.web
```

But It gives me the same result (I would like to avoid using this params anyway).

I tried different solutions and maven plugin configuration but this did not help me at all.

Im using Java 17
Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.oscar</groupId>
    <artifactId>mfe_ttn70_arn_detector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>mfe_ttn70_arn_detector</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.48</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx-fontawesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0-9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Fonts -->

        <!-- SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SLF4J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/java/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>pl.oscar.mfe_ttn70_arn_detector.ArnDetectorApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>mfe_ttn70_arn_detector_final</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>pl.oscar.mfe_ttn70_arn_detector.ArnDetectorApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is my module-info.java:

```java
module pl.oscar.mfe_ttn70_arn_detector {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;

    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires eu.hansolo.tilesfx;
    requires de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome;
    requires lombok;
    requires org.slf4j;
    opens pl.oscar.mfe_ttn70_arn_detector to javafx.fxml;
    exports pl.oscar.mfe_ttn70_arn_detector;
}
```

Paths to main class should be correct, but I'm leaving it here as well
Main source root path:

```
pl/oscar/mfe_ttn70_arn_detector/ArnDetectorApplication.java
```

Main content root path:

```
src/main/java/pl/oscar/mfe_ttn70_arn_detector/ArnDetectorApplication.java
```

Manifest content root path:

```
src/main/java/META-INF
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: pl.oscar.mfe_ttn70_arn_detector.ArnDetectorApplication
```

Do you have any idea what I could miss?

Edit:
Using backslashes:
1.

```
$ java -jar mfe_ttn70_arn_detector_final.jar --module-path D:\\programming\\javafx-sdk-19\\lib --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.fxml,javafx.web
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

2. 

```
$ java --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.fxml,javafx.web -jar mfe_ttn70_arn_detector_final.jar --module-path 
D:\\programming\\javafx-sdk-19\\lib
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found
```

Comment: You need the  `--module-path` and `--add-modules` options *before* the `-jar` options (otherwise they will be treated as program arguments, not VM arguments)

Comment: Trying it I'm getting output like this:
`$ java --module-path D:\programming\javafx-sdk-19\lib --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.fxml,javafx.web -jar mfe_ttn70_arn_detector_final.jar`

`Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 0: ?D:programmingjavafx-sdk-19lib`

Comment: Edit the question.  Add extra info there instead of comments.

Comment: Try using forward slashes (`/`), or escaping the backslashes (`\\`) in the paths. I haven't used windows in forever, I don't remember if the backslash is treated as an escape in VM args.

Comment: It gives me the same results using backslashes.

@jewelsea I don't have anything to add at this moment. I comments I've just put command that gives me InvalidPathException.

Comment: And if you use forward slashes, or escape the backslashes (i.e. use double backslashes, `\\ `)?

Comment: No changes using forward slashes, I've paste result of using backslashes at the end of post

Comment: Don't use the maven assembly `jar-with-dependencies` for a modular jar.  It will put all the dependencies inside one jar file, which for a modular app, is not allowed.  Instead, use `copy-dependencies`, and ensure the lib path for the dependencies are also on the module path.  See [baeldung maven assembly](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) for information on the difference between copy-dependencies and with-dependencies. Though, unfortunately, that tutorial does not discuss modular apps.

Comment: Consider if `jlink` or `jpackage` may not be a better packaging strategy for your app.

Comment: Don't specify the main class for a modular app using the manifest.  Instead, run a jar command that does something to the jar to configure the main class. See the related info on executable modular jars in the [Jenkov module tutorial](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java/modules.html#setting-the-jar-main-class). See sections: "Building a Java Module JAR File" and "Running a Java Module From a JAR".

Comment: When you specify the main class, you have to indicate the module used `pl.oscar.mfe_ttn70_arn_detector/pl.oscar.mfe_ttn70_arn_detector.ArnDetectorApplication`.  In your case, you have set the module name the same as your package name.  I don't advise characters like `_` in the module and package names. See "Module Naming" in the [Jenkov module tutorial](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java/modules.html#module-naming).

Comment: Are you actually using all of the dependencies you define?  If not, get rid of the ones you aren't using. I don't know why you would want both fontawesome and ikonli as they both do the same think and ikonli is superior. Also, I think you need to be using a modern version of slf4j (e.g. 2+) for it to work well as a module.

Comment: If you are going to use lombok, [you should use `requires static lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/setup/javac) in the module-info.  I don't advise lombok for JavaFX apps as I don't trust it will work well with JavaFX property conventions.  Also, lombok should be a [`provided`](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven) dependency and also requires configuration of the compiler plugin.